# What is the difference between cp -R foo/ and cp -R foo/*

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, asterisk

I noticed that whenever I use a command `cp -R foo/*` I copy everything except files like `.env` or probably `.gitignore`

The solution is to use `cp -R foo/` as it copes the whole directory, but this does not change the fact that I still don't understand the behaviour of using a `*` character.

Why a `*` character won't catch a files like `.env`?

The OS is Debian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `cp -R foo/` copies recursively everything under `foo/`
- `cp -R foo/*` copies recursively all the files and directories that match `foo/*`. And by default names with a dot are not included (`ls *` won't list them either). This is explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) (as well as some other little details about the leading dots).

Besides the handling of files with leading dots, another difference is that `cp -R foo/*` copies the individual files and directories in `foo/` to the target directory, while `cp -R foo/` makes a copy of `foo/` in the target directory (so you get one more directory level).

Answer (score 3):

By default globbing in bash does not include filenames starting with a `.`
So when you specify `*` you are asking to copy recursively without files starting with "`.`" . When you do not specify `*` it copies everything including "`.`" files.

Comment: What you are saying is (I suppose) based from what I wrote, but I never saw this specified in any documentation, for example tldp.org says that asterix character "can represent any number of characters (including zero, in other words, zero or more characters). If you specified a "cd*" it would use "cda", "cdrom", "cdrecord" and anything that starts with “cd” also including “cd” itself. "m*l" could by mill, mull, ml, and anything that starts with an m and ends with an l.".

Comment: check below for more details for same

Comment: man 7 glob .....

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you could use rsync to copy everything, including dot files and dot directories.

Comment: I'd like to point out that were you to do this as a superuser, the dot-files would then be picked up by the `*`, as files are not generally hidden from `root`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers you have, there are a couple of other cases where `foo/` and `foo/*` could be different (not just files beginning with `.`).  Besides, if you wanted to have files that start with `.` matched by your glob, you can enable that too with `shopt -s dotglob`.

The first is if there are no entries in `foo/` and you have not enabled `nullglob` then `foo/*` will be returned as a literal passed to `cp`.  Since (in this case) there isn't a source `foo/*` `cp` would complain, while `cp -R foo/` would always have at least `foo/` to copy.  If you did enable `nullglob` then `foo/*` would expand to nothing, so you'd end up missing an argument to `cp`.

Another case to consider is if there are a LOT of entries in `foo/`.  The shell expands the glob and then invokes the process, but if the glob expands to too many arguments you'll get an error.  With `cp -R foo/` you only have 2 arguments (though presumably you'll have a target somewhere else).